# Different PHP and MySQL date time

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an issue regarding date time returned by PHP and MySQL .
I checked PHP date, using

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
```

It returned

```
2013-07-31 01:07:37
```

then i executed a query in mysql console(phpmyadmin/sqlyog) with query

```
SELECT NOW() as date_time
```

it resulted

```
2013-07-31 15:40:36
```

Firslty I want that both should result dame date time, 
secondly how can i set any one of them to match the other one.

Note: I checked that on local and live server both

Comment: google for *sync php mysql datetime*

Comment: What does "I want that both should result dame date time" mean? Did you check DATE_FORMAT(date,format) ?

Comment: People the OP wants PHP server datetime and MySQL datetime being synchronized!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the typo in the format codes, it seems that MySQL and PHP are not configured to use the same time zone. How to find out?

[In MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone):

```
mysql> SELECT @@session.time_zone;
+---------------------+
| @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| SYSTEM              |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(In this example, `SYSTEM` means "the time zone of the host machine".)

[In PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php):

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
// Europe/Madrid
```

Comment: @IrfanYounus: I can see in your profile that you did not make use of a nice feature here on Stack Overflow by now. You can mark one answer per question as solution or best by clicking on the checkmark under the answer score. Maybe you also like to revisit your previous questions for that. And yu get 2 rep points per accept.

Answer (score 2):

Your `date` format string is wrong. It should read

```
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it says `h` is hours in 12-hour format and `m` is month, not minutes. The difference in two hours can be explained by timezone (and / or DST).

Comment: So? Does that typo change the situation?

Comment: Well it stops you using the month number as the minutes. it doesn't explain the Hour difference which may be due to non matching timezones

Comment: I corrected the month issue, but still i get different dates with PHP and MySQL query

Comment: @IrfanYounus what do you get, and what do you expect, and what is the timezone setting of your server, what would be correct UTC?